# Initializing components in the WindowsForms

Tags: c#, initialization, windows-forms-designer

In the WindowsForms what is the better way to initalize components:

- in the **properties** window?
- or in the **code** (in constructor)?

If I make it in the properties window, then I often have a situation, when I'm changing the value in the **code** and then closing the form. When I open it again, I'm getting old value (which I've written in **properties**) and it can confuse.

What is the differences between these two ways? Didn't found it in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent.

- When you change values using the properties window, that values are saved in the resx file. Then the method `InitializeComponents()`, that is written by the WinForms designed in the Form's constructor, performs the form initialization.
- If you do it manually in the constructor, you must place your initialization code, after `InitializeComponent()` method, then, the form will be initialized with your values.

What method is better? In my opinion, both method are equivalent. You can choose the way you prefer. But my recommendation is not mix them. Use pure Winforms designer or pure code initialization.